# Remove null attributes and empty children from Node

Tags: groovy

I have a [Node](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html) which I want to remove all `null` attributes and empty children from recursively before I write it to a file.  What I have below works, but it seems like there should be a built in method for this.  Have I missed something?

```
Node cleanNode(Node node) {

    // Find null attributes
    def attributesToRemove = []
    for(e in node.attributes()) {
        if(e.value == null) {
            attributesToRemove.add(e.key)
        }
    }

    // Remove null attributes
    for(attribute in attributesToRemove) {
        node.attributes().remove(attribute)
    }

    // Clean this node's children
    for(child in node.children()) {
        if(child instanceof Node) {
            cleanNode(child)
        }
    }

    // If node has no attributes, no children, and no text then discard it by setting it to null
    if(!node.attributes() && !node.children() && !node.text()) {
        node = null
    }

    node
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not a build in method for doing this that I know of...  You could get your code a little smaller (and recursively remove empty children) like so:

```
boolean cleanNode( Node node ) {
    node.attributes().with { a ->
        a.findAll { !it.value }.each { a.remove( it.key ) }
    }
    node.children().with { kids ->
        kids.findAll { it instanceof Node ? !cleanNode( it ) : false }
            .each { kids.remove( it ) }
    }
    node.attributes() || node.children() || node.text()
}
```

So given the xml:

```
def xml = '''<root>
            |  <head>
            |    <item>
            |       <woo/>
            |    </item>
            |  </head>
            |  <body att=''>
            |    <h1 name='' title='title'>
            |      woo
            |    </h1>
            |  </body>
            |  <tail>
            |    <item>hi</item>
            |  </tail>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()
```

We can parse it and clean it and print it out:

```
Node root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )
cleanNode( root )
println XmlUtil.serialize( root )
```

which gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <body>
    <h1 title="title">woo</h1>
  </body>
  <tail>
    <item>hi</item>
  </tail>
</root>
```

As you can see, the whole `<head>` block has been cleaned as it contained no information.

Comment: Your `cleanNode` method is very Groovy!

Comment: @ubiquibacon nice catch with the `attributes`/`children` bug (whoops)

Comment: One other thing I noticed is your use of "Groovy truth" for `!it.value`.  This will probably work for most people who read this so I didn't edit it in your answer, but for me I have to use `it.value == null` because I have attributes with a value of zero.

Comment: Won't they be Strings containing `'0'`?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can put an `int` as an attribute value when creating a node.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I was coming at it from an XML parsing angle

Comment: How to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

If the xml contains namespaces the `cleanNode` method will result in namespace declarations sprayed onto every node.
To avoid this use `new XmlParser(false, false)`, so the code becomes:

```
Node root = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
cleanNode(root)
println XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

This way the xml is nice and clean afterwards.

Many thanks to Tim for the original answer!