# Delete empty tags when testing with Jmeter

Tags: javascript, csv, jmeter

I am setting up some tests for Jmeter but i've encountered a problem which i've difficulty solving. In my JMS Point-to-Point i am using the following in the content section in JMeter content

[image]

i have a csv file with testdata for testing. All variables are written in this CSV with their value. for instance CoverageNr has a value of 1 then during testing Jmeter will use "< CoverageNr>1< /CovereageNr>" if it doesn't have a value it is empty: "< CoverageNr>< /CovereageNr>". And here we have the issue which i have. CoverageNr cannot be empty when used. What i want to achieve is when CoverageNr has no value, the tag "< CoverageNr>< /CovereageNr>" is not included in the test. I guess i have to make the entire tag configurable or use an if controller but so far to no avail. Can somebody give me some insights how to solve this problem?

Comment: So i've  added Beanshell Pre Processor as Dmitri T suggested in 2 other questions (Jmeter remove empty strings at a SOAP/xml reqeust
 and JMeter - Remove empty elements in SOAP request
) but i am oblivious on how to write a script for a JMS Point-to-Point test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard [Groovy is a new Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so you can do this as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the JMS Point to Point sampler
2. Put the following code into the "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

   def content = sampler.getContent()

   Node xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
   cleanNode(xml)

   def newContent = XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
   sampler.setContent(newContent)


   boolean cleanNode(Node node) {
       node.attributes().with { a ->
           a.findAll { !it.value }.each { a.remove(it.key) }
       }
       node.children().with { kids ->
           kids.findAll { it instanceof Node ? !cleanNode(it) : false }
                   .each { kids.remove(it) }
       }
       node.attributes() || node.children() || node.text()
   }
   ```

   Demo:[image: Groovy Remove Empty XML tags]

   Source: [Remove null attributes and empty children from Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388217/remove-null-attributes-and-empty-children-from-node)

Going forward I would recommend migrating to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) from Beanshell so in terms of performance it would be much better. Moreover Groovy has some nice sexy features, i.e. aforementioned [XML processing](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) so it will make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

So i've solved the issue thanks to the other questions mentioned in the comment above and thanks to Dmitri T's answers for those questions. using a Beanshell Pre Processor did the trick with script being:

```
String data = sampler.getContent();
data = data.replaceAll("<CoverageN></CoverageN>","");
sampler.setContent(data);
```

Maybe it can be usefull for others.